# react-native-maps "onRegionChangeComplete" function firing when user not interacting with map (Android)

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

Im using react-native 0.59.5 and react-native-maps 0.26.0.
I set "region" prop on "MapView" component to users location as part of componentWillMount....this works fine.

However for some reason the onRegionChangeComplete event is called anywhere between 0 and 5 times after app is loaded....when user is not even interacting with it.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: have you found any solution i am facing same issue

Comment: Unfortunately I have not :(